# How to get what pages user visits(in realtime)

Tags: laravel

I have to get what pages user visits(in realtime). I have a little app with admin page where I have to see in real-time on what page each user visits. Need a piece of helpful advice about how I could do this. Should I use WebSockets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `request()->url()` helper function in your `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider`'s `boot` method

```php
public function boot()
{
   info(request()->url());
}
```

This for example will log any url a user visits

For Example

Given routes like this

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('page', function () {
    return back();
});
```

If you accessed the app and navigated through some urls, you'd get this in the log

```
[2019-09-23 22:05:19] testing.INFO: https://laravel.dev
[2019-09-23 22:05:26] testing.INFO: https://laravel.dev/page
[2019-09-23 22:05:26] testing.INFO: https://laravel.dev
[2019-09-23 22:08:42] testing.INFO: https://laravel.dev/home
[2019-09-23 22:09:39] testing.INFO: https://laravel.dev/register  
[2019-09-23 22:09:41] testing.INFO: https://laravel.dev/login  
[2019-09-23 22:09:42] testing.INFO: https://laravel.dev/password/reset  
[2019-09-23 22:09:51] testing.INFO: https://laravel.dev/password/email
```

Comment: This is great but where should I look for the output testing.INFO? Should I open another question for this?

Comment: I've found it. This file is stored in app/storage/logs/laravel.log. Thank you for the answer!